# React Bootstrap Carousal styling not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

My react boot strap carousel isn't rendering with the proper styling.

```
import React from "react";
import RBCarousel from "react-bootstrap-carousel";

export default class StampCards extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="slider-container">
            <RBCarousel animation={true} autoplay={false} slideshowSpeed= 
             {2000} version={4} onSelect={this.onSelect} ref={r => 
            (this.slider = r)}>
                <div>Page1</div>
                <div>Page2</div>
            </RBCarousel>
       </div>
);}}
```

Here's what renders
[image]

But what I want is something like this
https://skycloud1030.github.io/react-bootstrap-carousel/example/demoV3.html

**Problem was I forgot to import the bootstrap css**

Comment: where have you imported the css?

Comment: The css import is missing. `
import "react-bootstrap-carousel/dist/react-bootstrap-carousel.css";`

Comment: As per docs you also need bootstrap css which is missing. import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"; docs here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-carousel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try import

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "react-bootstrap-carousel/dist/react-bootstrap-carousel.css";
```